# iOS) How to change location of already added subview

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, addsubview

I have three views : topView, middleView, bottomView.

When I clicked the button in the topView, I want to insert alpha view between topView and middleView.

but middleView and bottomView is already located by calling method [self.view addsubView:] at viewDidLoad.

So I have to change middleView and bottomView below the alpha view...

So I called method 'setFrame', but already added views didn't move to where i want to put them.

So I have to call method 'removeFromSuperView' but there is a big problem that middleView and bottomView are the master views that has multiple subviews into them...

I don't know how to solve this problem, please help me!

! middleView and bottomView, they just need to go down , moving issue is simple.

****UPDATE
My code about the issue is below :

authCodeView is alphaView

```
authCodeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, topView.frame.size.height + 8, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, topView.frame.size.height)];
[authCodeView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
authCodeField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30, 0, authCodeView.frame.size.width - 30, authCodeView.frame.size.height)];
authCodeField.attributedPlaceholder = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"인증번호 입력" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:tempGray}];
[authCodeView addSubview:authCodeField];

NSLog(@"%f",authCodeView.frame.origin.y+authCodeView.frame.size.height + 8);
[middleView setFrame:CGRectMake(100, authCodeView.frame.origin.y+authCodeView.frame.size.height + 8, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 308.0f)];
[bottomView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, middleView.frame.origin.y+middleView.frame.size.height+8, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, bottomView.frame.size.height)];


[self.view addSubview:authCodeView];
[self.view addSubview:middleView];
[self.view addSubview:bottomView];
```

Comment: Share your code pls.

Comment: Try to remove `removeFromSuperView` (remove `[self.view addSubview:middleView];
[self.view addSubview:bottomView];` also), and call `setNeedDisplay` after change frame of `middleView` and `bottomView`

Comment: It doens't work ... I removed what you said

Comment: Yes. If it doesn't work, try `[self setNeedsDisplay]`. One more thing: if you remove then add again, the middle and bottom view go down properly?

Comment: I thought about autolayout, middle and bottomview has some constraints , isn't it affect? @anhtu

Comment: Yes, if you are using autolayout with some constraints, for sure you can't update frame like this. You should update the constraints.

Comment: I did [self.view setNeedsDisplay] but unfortunately it doesn't work, do you mean I have to add subview for middle view and bottom view again?

Comment: Wow, it drives me very crazy... it's first time to code for constraints programmatically

Comment: "It doesn't work" is an insufficient description -- what do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: And yes, if you're using auto layout you can't expect to just move views around. You'll need to adjust the constraints instead.

Comment: I'm sorry for my short explanation, I mean middle and bottomview stays their original position strongly

Comment: My expectation is that middle view and bottom view is below authCodeView but they stays their position and I think authCodeView is behind middleview

Comment: Try to do something with your constraints, update frame won't work. Don't remove and add again.

Answer (score 1):

> So I called method 'setFrame', but already added views didn't move to where i want to put them.

Then you passed the wrong rectangle to `-setFrame:`. That method changes the frame of the view, i.e. it's location and size in the coordinate system of its superview.

> So I have to call method 'removeFromSuperView' but there is a big problem that middleView and bottomView are the master views that has multiple subviews

You don't need to remove a view just to change its position. You'd only need to remove it if you want to add it to some other view instead, or if you no longer want it in the superview at all. That said, it's not a problem if a view like `middleView` has subviews -- those will go along with `middleView` if you remove it from its superview, or if you change `middleView`'s position, etc.

> I don't know how to solve this problem, please help me!

When asking for help, you really need to post code that reproduces the problem you're trying to solve.